# How can I get content from php array to js array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have problem with a convert php array to js array. It is my code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require "db.inc.php";

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `pixels`, `status` FROM datagame WHERE `id_user`='$id'");
$stmt->execute();

$result_array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

And JS:

```
let arr = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/test.inc.php",
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      arr = JSON.parse(data);
  i=0;
  while (i<=Object.keys(arr).length) {
    alert(arr.pixels[i]);
    i++;
  }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus);
    });
});
```

And it is working and not working. I have this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> What can I do?

Comment: The error message tells that `arr.pixels` doesn't exist. `console.log(arr)` after parsing it, you'll see what you've got from the server.

Comment: I got this:
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
pixels: "pix39"
status: "1"
__proto__: Object
1: {pixels: "pix60", status: "1"}
2: {pixels: "pix98", status: "1"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Please add the log result to the post, and format it as code, it'll be clearer that way.

Comment: Now when having the data, we can see, that you've an array of objects. Instead of the `while` loop, do `arr.forEach(function (obj) {alert(obj.pixels);});`. You could also add the data code to the question itself, and delete the answer. Answers are for ... well ... answers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/test.inc.php",
  })
    .done(function (data) {
      arr = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(arr);
      arr.forEach(function (obj) {
        alert(obj.pixels);
      });
      
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus);
    });
});
```

forEach it works nothing more errors.